# 'Start Rollout to Production' button disabled

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I'm trying to release an app to the Google Play store. I've gone through all the required steps in the Google Play Console (play.google.com/apps/publish)

But when I click App Releases on the left, then click Edit Release under Production, add an APK then click Review on the bottom, it takes me to the "Confirm rollout to production: 1.0" page, with the familiar START ROLLOUT TO PRODUCTION button on the bottom. That button is greyed out so I can't click it. The Review Summary at the top of the page says "This release is ready to be rolled out."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Make sure you completed all stages

[image]

Comment: I was hoping they'd put your "Make sure you completed all stages" above the disabled "Start Rollout" button. That'd be really helpful.

Comment: they desperately need some form validation on this page. had to come here to find out what else they needed from me...

Comment: Things have been updated (or broken may be) little bit. Now there is an **App content** section. I am still stuck. Can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175487/ads-section-in-play-store-is-empty

Answer (score 29):

I had a grey triangle with an exclamation point to the right of "Store Listing" in the pane to the left. Hovering over it, it said "You need to add at least 2 non-Android TV screenshots." Uploaded another screenshot and now there is a green checkmark instead of the triangle, and the release button is enabled.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. The tick for the items with some pending tasks were greyed tick. After I complete the tasks, the tick become green.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem and it is solved. **There was a pending task to complete.**

Put you mouse hover the one menu marked in "grey", you will see a tooltip showing you the point to correct. correct that point and that Menu will be marked in "green".

**In order for you to deploy, all Important Menus must be marked in "green":**

- App release
- Store Listing
- Content Rating
- Pricing and Distribution

Hope this will help

Comment: And, we need to make sure that the mandatory steps in "App Content" are also completed and marked as Green.

Comment: In my case, had a draft release in production. It was only showing info in the tooltip! Not very user friendly. Ohwell, I cleared that and could progress. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

In 2019 you need complete process

- App content

And following steps

- App release
- Store Listing
- Content Rating
- Pricing and Distribution

Comment: Sequence matter? See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175487/ads-section-in-play-store-is-empty

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem recently and I figured out that we have to complete 5 important tasks in order to make our application ready.

1. App Release.
2. Store Listing.
3. Content Rating.
4. Pricing And Distribution.
5. App Content.

Note: Any of these, if not completed, will result in disabling of the "Start Rolling Out To Production" button.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time it's the "Store listing" menu item being greyed out.
The two most common scenarios are when you forget to add screenshots or forget to check the "privacy policy" checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you manually select a country in the `Pricing and Distribution` section.  It's really weird that the default is to select NO COUNTRIES at all.  But that's google for you.