# Ads section in Play Store is empty

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I am uploading app on Play Store. I have completed all required forms and inputs however when I go to **App Content -> Ads**, it doesn't show any input field. Is there any issue or I need to first complete something else?

[image]

I have opted App Alpha Testing track and uploaded **App Bundles**. However, only this Ads thing is left for Alpha Rollout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disable adblocker in your browser